# An update from Jelly Bean fails at 30%

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, ota-update

I have a galaxy S3 SGH i747, Jelly Bean 4.3.  The update is downloaded but every time it attempts to update, it fails at 30%. What to do now?

Comment: Can you get the OTA from somewhere on the Web(Trustworthy source)? You can update the system via stock recovery then. It won't void your warranty. Otherwise, are you on wifi or data-pack while downloading the update. You may try Factory-reset to see if things works out better.

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry, i dont think there is any other option. The KitKat update for **Galaxy S3** on AT&T is only downloadable via **OTA** (Over The Air). You cannot update for some unkown reason, that is, unless you are willing to **FACTORY RESET** your phone in order to be able to update.

(there is another **VERY COMPLEX WAY** on fixing this, it will involve ADB, Rooting, Putting your phone at risk, and voiding your warranty.... So i would not reccomend that, but tell me if you **STILL** want me to tell you the other way. But please note that you would be putting your phone at risk.)